# How to encode value with jquery serialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to encode all values like

```
encodeURIComponent($("#customer_details").serialize());
```

and that doesn't work as expected.

Is there way to get all elements on form and use `encodeURIComponent` to encode each value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should already be encoded when using the [`serialize()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

*From the docs:*

> The `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WArUG/

If you want to represent a space with a `%20` instead of a `+`, you'll need to do a `.replace(/\+/g,'%20')`.