# jQuery post with form.serialize() receives null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post

When I post a HTML.Form with jQuery in the following syntax:

```
$.post('<%: Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName") %>',
             $("#FormName").serialize());
```

the object is posted correctly to the server, but if I use:

```
var reason = encodeURIComponent($("#FormName").serialize());
$.post('<%: Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName") %>',
                        { reason: reason });
```

the serialized object is null, I get the same result when I use encodeURIComponent or without it.
I need to send more parameter data to the server, that is why I want to use the second method, but I can't get it to send the serialized object correctly.

Comment: One look at the posted data (with with Fiddler or some other inspecting tool) will show you the problem. URI encode individual data points, not the entire posted serialized string.

Comment: Thanks, is there possibly a different way to encode it?

Comment: I am pretty sure the data it already encoded: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6653908/426894 http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ `The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.`

Comment: I checked with fiddler and the difference in the body is this: reason=Type=1&Comments=&ID=15 vs Type=1&Comments=&ID=15 where the expected variable name in my server side call is "reason". So it seems the serialized string should be boxed in somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by boxing the serialized string with [] when posting the data:

```
var reason = $("#FormName").serialize();
$.post('<%: Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName") %>',
                    { reason: [reason] });
```

When checking with HTTP Fiddler the difference in the body of the post was when doing this:

```
var reason = $("#FormName").serialize();
$.post('<%: Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName") %>',
                    { reason: reason });
```

the body tag held something like this: reason=Type=1&Comments=&ID=15 so it could not differentiate in what the variable actually held. By boxing it in with [] the body tag now contains: reason%5B%5D=Type%3D1%26Comments%3D%26ID%3D1 thus correctly encoding the posted data.