# Ajax form gets sometimes urlencoded

Tags: php, jquery, urlencode

I have an own made ticket system and lately I have an annoying thing going on. What's happening is that sometimes when making reply, all spaces are being replaced with the + sign. So far it is only happening recently and only at certain messages, so not all of them. I haven't been able to detect a special condition or character in the messages where it is happening.

The code is as following:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#newticket, #addreply', function () {
    $(".loadingadd").show();
    var eid = $(this).attr("id");
    var xform = $(this).serialize();
    $("#"+eid+" :input").prop("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/a/tickets",
        dataType: "json",
        data: xform,
        success: function(data) {
```

The Form:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="" method="post" id="addreply">
```

I'm using Firefox 50.1.0.

I have not been able to catch the event in Firebug in action, so there is a chance the server side is causing it, but I doubt that since it's not happening every time.

Does anyone know if a browser can decide to urlencode a POST or something? Or should I always encode in JS and decode server side? If so, how to do this with the serialize?

[How to encode value with jquery serialize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653878/how-to-encode-value-with-jquery-serialize)

I saw this, but I don't have that currently and yet I only sometimes have the + signs. And doesn't that replace removes valid + uses?

Basically I'm now just using the serialize to send the form, and using $_POST['message'] to get the contents, not using any decoding or encoding.

Or should I specify an enctype? If I read http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp the + sign is only not replaced when using multipart/form-data?

Anyone knows whats going on here and what I should use for forms, ajax encoding and server side (php) decoding? Whats best practice?

Comment: Parameters are supposed to be URL-encoded, this is perfectly normal. The default format for POST requests is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: And the server is supposed to decode them. Most frameworks for writing server-side scripts take care of this automatically. E.g. in PHP, `$_POST` and `$_GET` contain the decoded parameters.

Comment: I'm using $_POST indeed, maybe it doesn't get encoded properly so the server can't decode it?

Comment: Go to the Network tab of Developer Tools, and look at the raw request data. What do you see there?

Comment: @Arie Have you tried using `urldecode($_POST['message']);` on the php side?

Comment: The problem is, it only happens at certain times. I'm trying to reproduce it, but it goes fine. If I just put a urldecode on it, I definitely will lose valid + signs I believe. Still trying different messages atm.

Comment: Okay I've located the problem. There is a $.ajaxPrefilter that acts when a CSRF token exipres and unserializes the data object, changes the CSRF token and retries the ajax request. It's going wrong there. Thanks for for the replies, I'm gonna try to fix this.

Comment: In case anyone happens to use the $.unserialize gist, https://gist.github.com/brucekirkpatrick/7026682#gistcomment-1442581 is the one who fixes my problem. The difference is that it actually replaces the + sign with a space.